# i have 4 table in sql and i want the data or all the table where one unique key is matched in four of them

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table ratings, bookmark, checkin, food in food table there is a unique key sno and this sno key is used in remaining three tables.

food table

```
    sno  name     totalrating   totalcheckin      
    1    nitesh      52                 45
    2    abhishek    4                  9
    3    divye       42                 30
```

ratings table

```
    sno  datakey     rated    name 
    1      3           3.0    divye
    1      6           4.0    shashank
```

bookmark table

```
    sno  datakey     name 
    1      3         divye
    1      6         shashank
```

Checkin table

```
    sno  datakey     name 
    1      2         abhishek 
    1      6         shashank
```

I need data where datakey is 3 if not present show null values and data key column not repeated

like

```
 0    1           2             3            4    5       6        7     8         9     10  
sno  name     totalrating   totalcheckin   sno  rated    name     sno   name     sno     name
3    divye       42             30          1     3.0     divye    1   divye     null     null
```

Comment: Look at joins in SQL, that will help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query should look like this:

```
SELECT f.sno, f.name, f.totalrating, f.totalcheckin, 
       r.sno, r.rated, r.name, 
       b.sno, b.name,
       c.sno, c.name
FROM food AS f
 LEFT JOIN ratings AS r
  ON f.sno = r.datakey
LEFT JOIN bookmark AS b
  ON f.sno = b.datakey
LEFT JOIN checkin AS c
  ON f.sno = c.datakey
WHERE f.sno = 3
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61ec1/5) to see how it's work.

Also I agree with the guys in the comment which are told you to read something about JOIN syntax. It's pretty and you can start [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), or more specific for your problem is [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), that is the begin and good place to start. Also you can see that I use aliases in my query about that read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

GL!

P.S. (edit) and if you have any question fill free to ask... Also I notice that you have name column in every table, if I understand relation between your table it's not necessary. You should store name only in first table (food) and with simple JOIN from there you can pull that data whenever you need it!